# Divide canvas into multiple stripes using RGB

Tags: java, canvas, rgb

I want to divide the canvas into 8 vertical black and white Stripes. I wrote a method changeValue to change the value of the color everytime the loop is executed but the canvas is complete white. I think my changeValue method doesn't do as supposed but I can't explain why.

So far I got this:

```
public class Stripe {

    public boolean switch = false;

    private void stripes(int[] pixels, int width, int height) {
        // TODO set some values here
        int counter = 1;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int pos = y * width + x;
                int r, g, b;
                // TODO code for the flag.
                r = 255;
                g = 255;
                b = 255;

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    if (x < (counter * (width - 1)) / 8) {
                        r = changeValue();
                        g = changeValue();
                        b = changeValue();
                    }
                    counter++;
                    switch ^= true;

                }

                pixels[pos] = 0xFF000000 | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
            }
        }
    }

    public int changeValue() {
        if (switch) {
            return 255;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I am supposed not to write 8 If statements for the 8 stripes but this for example is the code for the Italian flag which are 3 vertical Stripes but which actually works:

```
private void flagItalian(int[] pixels, int width, int height) {
    // TODO set some values here
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int pos = y * width + x;
            int r, g, b;
            // TODO code for the flag.
            r = 255;
            g = 0;
            b = 0;
            if (x < 2 * (width - 1) / 3) {
                r = 255;
                g = 255;
                b = 255;
            }
            if (x < (width - 1) / 3) {
                r = 0;
                g = 255;
                b = 0;
            }
            pixels[pos] = 0xFF000000 | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use switch as a name for a variable, as it is also used in a switch statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need alternating color stripes then you could go for the classic odd/even checks. Instead of you below code block

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  if (x < (counter * (width - 1)) / 8) {
    r = changeValue();
    g = changeValue();
    b = changeValue();
  }
 counter++;
 switch ^= true;

}
```

Try replacing with this one

```
if (x%2) {
  r = 255;
  g = 255;
  b = 255
} else {
  r = 0;
  g = 0;
  b = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro! But now I get a high number of stripes, but I only want 8.

Comment: That i can help on seeing how you print your RGBs. From the height and width loops you have used i guessed you print this in a 8X8 matrix format.